# Invalid Login: 535 Incorrect authentication data Nuxt Mail

Tags: javascript, vue.js, smtp, nuxt.js, nodemailer

I've 535 Incorrect authentication Error while using Nuxt Mail Module, only when I try to send an email on the deployed site ( on the server) I get the error

When I try to send an email from localhost It works fine, but when I deploy it to the server I'll get that error

The only difference is deployed site is over HTTPS,
I don't know exactly what happened that I get this error but I hadn't this problem a week ago even on the deployed version
These are my nuxt-configs for email:

```js
 modules: [
  ['nuxt-mail', {
      message: [
        {name:'ticket',to: 'webticket@site.com'},
        {name:'contact',to: 'contactus@site.com'}
      ],
      smtp: {
        host: "mail.site.com",
        port: 587,
        auth: {
          user: 'webticket@site.com',
          pass: 'Aa123456'
        },
        secure: false,
        tls: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
      },
    }],
  ],
```

This is the error :
[image: 535 Incorrect authentication]

Comment: Do you use hard-coded authentication data?

Comment: Yes but the username & email address that I shared here isn't the same

Comment: Shouldn't `secure` be set to `true`? Also, can you check what you're sending in your payload (`headers` tab on your screen) and compare it to what is sent on the production server? Otherwise, since this is a backend issue, the fastest way here would be to check the logs on the backend!

Comment: Do you have secure server logs? I would try to debug and verify that the credentials are valid by trying to print the password

Comment: Another thing, how do you deploy your service? Maybe the deployment mechanism makes changes..

Comment: On top of the above, you can also try to debug the thing with a Postman call, just to see if it's a whitelist thing (maybe only localhost is allowed) or another issue.

Comment: @kissu , secure – if true the connection will use TLS when connecting to server. If false (the default) then TLS is used if server supports the STARTTLS extension. In most cases set this value to true if you are connecting to port 465. For port 587 or 25 keep it false

Comment: @Arik I only use yarn build command then I move build files to the server and I'll install node modules and npm start ! nothing else happens, I tried sending email with gmail with different configs again it works in localhost but not on the server

Comment: Seems mail address hasn't valid SSL certificate and it cause the problem our back-end dev is working on it